# Converting matplotlib plots into a json object

Tags: python, json, matplotlib

I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
Zn  Pb    Ag  Cu  Mo   Cr  Ni  Co   Ba
87   7  0.02  42   2   57  38  14  393
70   6  0.02  56   2   27  29  20  404
75   5  0.02  69   2   44  23  17  417
70   6  0.02  54   1   20  19  12  377
```

I have defind the following function that takes each column of the above dataset and plot some statistical charts like histogram, boxplot, etc.

```py
def statistical_plots(desired_column):

    values = given_df.loc[:, f'{desired_column}'].values
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=[8, 8])

     # plot1 => histogram
     # the code that creates histogram

     # plot2 => boxplot
     # the code that creates boxplots

     # plot3 => Q-Q plot
     # the code that creates q-q plot

     # plot4 => P-P plot
     # the code that creates p-p plot

     plt.suptitle(f'Basic Statistical Plots of {desired_column}')
     fig.tight_layout()
     plt.savefig("Basic Statistical Plots of {}".format(desired_column), format='raw', dpi=75,
                        bbox_inches='tight')
```

I used to iterate over this function using a very simple `for` loop to have plots for all of the given elements of the dataset in each column. But, I **do not** want to **save** the files in `raw` format, which is basically a json file. I want to **create a json object** and save each plot in the json object. Something like below:

```json
{
  "Basic Statistical Plots of Zn": {
    "# some data representing the graph"
    },
  "Basic Statistical Plots of Pb": {
    "# some data representing the graph"
    },
  "Basic Statistical Plots of Ag": {
    "# some data representing the graph"
    },
  ...
}
```

How matplotlib plots can be added to a json object?